# Will metro style windows 8 apps support local database access?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to build a metro style win 8 app which needs to access a local database (installed on the users pc) of information such as sql express.

The current beta builds of win 8 dont seem to support that. Has Microsoft released any info on whether this will be supported? Something like ado.net, entity framework, linq sql?

Comment: Since this is closed I cannot create an answer directly. But let me answer here. Desktop services like a locally installed database are not accessible from Metro. However, embedded databases are. To that end, in the Consumer Preview, an embedded Microsoft SQL CE is not supported. There has been no announcement yet as to its support - but like Windows Phone, we can only assume this support is in the pipeline. In the meantime, if cloud wont work and local files wont work, I have seen third party stores (like SqlLite) used. It's not ideal. But, it's (at least) an option for developers.

Comment: This question should not have been closed until it had an answer. I get asked this question all the time. It's important for metro developers to know what their options are.

Comment: Closing this question really makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Windows 8 Metro style apps will not support connecting to a local database. That is to say, you will not be able to use a kind of connectionstring where you can say connect to server X. This has to do with the "Market store" principle that applications should work out of the box without configuring a database connection.

Probably there will be support for a local database as in Windows Phone 7 (SQL CE) with Linq to sql on top of it.

If you would like to access a database that's in a central location, than you will have to expose the data from the database with webservices which can be consumed by your metro style application.

Comment: By local database, i mean a sql express db installed on the users computer. It sounds like you are saying this scenario will be possible. Is sql express installable and accessible from a metro app now in the win 8 developers preview?

Comment: What i tried to say is that you can't connect to a local database installed on your pc. Windows phone has the concept that's called local database which adds a SQL CE database to your local storage. I think that the kind of Windows Phone concept will be available in Windows 8. What you try to achieve will not be possible.

Comment: Due to Network Isolation you won't be able to connect to SQL Express or other local database servers. There are some projects out there such as http://winrtdatabase.codeplex.com/ that are attempts to address this functionality.